# Javascript: Overwrite ONLY existing fields in one object with the fields in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Is there a way in javascript 
to assign values of named fields in an object to the same fields of another object, if and only if the target field exists. I.e. overwrite old values, NOT adding new values, using ideomatic constructs, one-liners (special for javascript and/or jQuery) and in no way loops, even for-in.

```
var theSource = {
 field1: "TEXT",
 field2: "VAL",
 field3: "ZZ",
 field4: "4",
 field5: "5"
},
theTarget = {
 field2: "0",
 field3: "",
 field4: null,
 field5: undefined
};
```

Something like

```
var result = jQuery.overwriteOnlyExisting(theTarget, theSource);
result === {
 field2: "VAL"
 field3: "ZZ"
... 
}
```

NO field1 AND old fields after field3 are preserved.

`jQuery.extend` - can overwrite values, but it copies new fields as well.

Which options do we have here?

http://jsbin.com/owivat/1/edit (underscore) - I like this, now the time to find the jquery way.

Results:

```
_.extend(theTarget, _(theSource).pick(_(theTarget).keys()));
```

142,850 Ops/sec

```
Object.keys(theTarget).map(function(a) { if (a in theSource) theTarget[a] = theSource[a]; });
```

403,243 Ops/sec

Comment: why *...and in no way loops, even for-in* ?

Comment: You should use http://underscorejs.org/#each and http://backbonejs.org/#Model-has for that. Basicly it is for-in loop on the source and object.hasOwnProperty on the target.

Comment: @inf3rno cool to know, but stuck with jQuery :)

Comment: with only standard js we can do:   Object.keys(theTarget).map(function(a){ if(theSource[a]) theTarget[a]=theSource[a]})

Comment: jquery is just for DOM manipulation, so you won't do that with jquery... btw it's an easy task with standard javascript...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's the one-liner :)

```
for(var propertyName in theTarget)theTarget[propertyName]&&(theTarget[propertyName]=theSource[propertyName]);
```

with `underscore.js` you can do:

```
_(theTarget).extend(_(theSource).pick( _(theTarget).keys() ));
```

Comment: it's wrong concept of the one-liner :) one liners are cool things we could do with map/splice/filter/regex and so on. Thanks for making it funny.

Comment: @gr9zev check out underscore, it's great for functional programming

Comment: Check out comments to OP. Still can 'pick' get a object as a parameter? if one have to manually list all fields - it's nonsence.

Comment: so, tested http://jsbin.com/owivat/1/edit and it works, still it's overhead to use jquery and _ at the same time...

Answer (score 6):

OK! oneliner! no visible loops!

```
Object.keys(theTarget).map(function(a){ if(theSource[a]) theTarget[a]=theSource[a]})
```

Though map has a loop in it's source I'm sure. but I think this the only way to do it without a visible loop construct. though it abuses javascript's global namespace and is therefore dirty.

Okay, even better:

```
Object.keys(theTarget).map(function(a){ if(Object.keys(theSource).indexOf(a)) theTarget[a]=theSource[a]})
```

and more concise

```
keys(theTarget).map(function(a){ if(a in theSource) theTarget[a]=theSource[a]})
```

though keys() and Array#indexOf wont work in older ecma versions.

Comment: It's better, but I've seen js magic, the must be some built-in check for 'if(theSource[a])'. Plus mind the answer of Poetro, this solution won't work with theSource[a] === '', 0, null and so on

Comment: ok, here is a better one.  Array#indexOf should work perfectly.

Comment: I don't think this can be refactored to be an more concise.

Comment: We'll see) but it's good, it's better with Object: Object.keys(theTarget).map(function(a){ if (a in theSource) theTarget[a] = theSource[a]; });

Answer (score 5):

You can do it manually, I don't understand why "no loops". jQuery is looping too in some way or another:

```
var result = {};
for (var key in theSource) {
  if (theTarget[key]) result[key] = theSource[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through the `source`'s keys, check if they exists (not if they are *truthy* as that wont copy over `0`, `''`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`) and copy that value to the result object. Since you don't want to overwrite the source or target, don't modify them.

```
jQuery.overwriteOnlyExisting = function (source, target) {
    var result = {}, key;
    for (key in target) {
        result[key] = key in source ? source[key] : target[key];
    }
    return result
};
```

Comment: valid point, that's why I try to rely on much more elaborate mechanisms of js and jquery, not to get into a trap of 'forgetting something'.

Answer (score 1):

```
var theSource = {
 field1: "TEXT",
 field2: "VAL",
 field3: "ZZ",
 field4: "4",
 field5: "5"
},
theTarget = {
 field2: "0",
 field3: "",
 field4: null,
 field5: undefined
};

var overrideExistingProperties = function (theTarget, theSource){
    for (var property in theSource)
        if (theSource.hasOwnProperty(property) && theTarget.hasOwnProperty(property))
            theTarget[property] = theSource[property];
};

overrideExistingProperties(theTarget, theSource);
result = theTarget; //if you don't want to clone
```